# Cordova iOS - Facebook Native App callback return issue?

Tags: ios, cordova-plugins, phonegap-plugins

1. I have integration/implement Facebook Login in **Demo.framework**.
2. Import Demo.framework in my own Cordova Custom Plugin.
3. Within (FBLoginViewController.m) Custom Plugin call my Demo.framework's function (it's working).
4. Create Cordova Demo and within demo i have < button /> tag with onClick() method in index.html file and call fbLoginMethod (function) which is define in Custom Plugin's FBLoginViewController.m file.
5. When FBLoginManage Class open Facebook Native App for Authentication. After Authentication success FBSDK delegate not getting return at index.html.

***Note* : Without Facebook Native App same Login process scenario is working (within SFSafariViewController).**